# How to add list of checkboxes [combo boxes] to JScrollPane in Java Netbeans Swing application

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a list of names and associated values to create checkboxes like

```
["SAMABULA","CARPETS INTERNATIONAL","HRM/TRAINING"]
["091","094","003"]
```

How to create checkboxes with these values add these checkboxes to JScrollPane in Netbeans IDE.

This is a Swing application. I created a window from palette and added jscrollpane to that window. But I don't know how to add list of checkboxes to that scrollpane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Srikanth Dyapa

there are two areas

you have already [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) that's contains [JCheckBox(es)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox)

then you just declare

```
JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(myList);
```

or you have to put your [JCheckBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) to [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) but for JPanel with correct [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for example [GridLaoyut](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

thenarter add your JList or JPanel to the JScrollPane as is above mentioned

maybe [ButtonGroup Component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) can help you with that

Comment: please edit your original quesion and put here your code (without concern ..), here are lots of people who will hepl you with that, and don't forget by using code tags button `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to add them in NetBeans as i use Eclipse, but in code would be something like:

```
JCheckBox chk = new JCheckBox("[LABEL STRING]");
// add event listeners to chk
myScrollPane.add(chk);
```

see here for more detail and examples: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: question is about list of checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans you just drag and drop the Check Boxes where you need them. In an Action Listener you use `jCheckBox1.isSelected()` in order to check if the user has checked the box or not.